# Numbers generation bad value

Tags: algorithm, scala, math

I would like to implementing Bernoulli numbers generation in Scala. I select [this algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli_number#Algorithmic_description). I wrote following code:

```
def bernoulli(n: Int) = {

val a: Array[Fraction] = Array.fill(n + 1) {
  new Fraction()
}

for (m <- 0 to n) {

  a(m) = new Fraction(1, m + 1, 1 / (m + 1F))

  for (j <- m to 1 by -1) {

    val vc = a(j - 1)
    vc.value= j * (vc.value - a(j).value)
  }

}
a.head


 }

  class Fraction(var numerator: Int = 0, var denominator: Int = 0, var value: Float = 0)
```

But when I print `bernoulli(5)` it is not 0.

Comment: Please demonstrate well-formatted code and reduce the example to the part that goes wrong. Stack Overflow is not a debugging service.

Comment: And tell us the actual result. If it's close to zero, it's probably (expected) floating point errors

Comment: what do you do with `vc`? it's any reasonable case to compute it and do nothing with it?

Answer (score 1):

The code that you are using seems to work fine. The reason that you don't get 0 is because of floating point errors. If you want more accurate results, you can use [BigDecimal](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.math.BigDecimal) rather than floats.

To use BigDecimal, use `a(m) = new Fraction(1, m + 1, 1 / BigDecimal(m + 1))` and use BigDecimal for the class.

By using BigDecimal, you will get

```
    bernoulli(5).value  //> res0: BigDecimal = -1.00E-32
```

which is close to 0.